# Soldering RoHS components with Pb-Sn solder

Tags: soldering

How is soldering RoHS components with good old Pb-Sn solder different from soldering non-RoHS components? I'm talking about hand-soldering, not wave or reflow.

Comment: I've heard rumors of Pb-Sn solder being incompatible with certain RoHS PCB finishes.  Does anyone have real data about this?

Comment: @mark: I found [this page](http://www.uyemura.com/solder_joint_reliability.htm) that suggests ENEPIG (EN, electroless paladium, IG) finishes don't get along with Pb-Sn that well.  The question seems to be more about just adding RoHS parts to an otherwise PbSn process though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to make any process changes, as most RoHS components are plated with 100% matte tin, which is compatible with PbSn.

I've only heard of problems when mixing RoHS and non-RoHS for very fine-pitch, leadless packages as the stresses they can generate (leaded components have a little give) are much less tolerant of any undesirable intermetallics, and especially BGAs as they bring their own solder (balls) to the party (though hand soldering BGAs is extremely dubious at best.)

Assuming you've been using leaded solder with non-RoHS components before, keep the temperature the same, the matte tin coating needs negligible additional heat relative to everything else to dissolve into the tin-lead solder.

Comment: I think the rule still stands that youneed to always check the datasheet.

Comment: @Kortuk: True, though when it says matte tin plated, all systems go.

Comment: I thought your info was rock solid, was your first +1, but I thought I would add that for others.